# How can i connect crystal reports 2011 with apache tomcat 7 by jndi?

Tags: tomcat, jndi, crystal-reports-2011

I want to use crystal reports to make reports for a project in java, i have to use a jndi connection to use apache tomcat 7 as a jndi provider , i've been looking several tutorials but any of them is explicit enough, i'd like a tutorial that helps me do this.

Comment: I added this code in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml 
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/MyDataSource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="abc" password="abc" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
               url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.123.123.123:1521:xe"/>
               <!-- // tried both driver class names but all not work driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" -->
</Context>

Comment: i dont know if i have to add something in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml or ir TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's working for me:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MyDataSourceSameNameOfWhatIsInTnsNames"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
username="MyUserName"
password="MyPassword"
driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@  (DESCRIPTION =    (ADDRESS_LIST =      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = My.Ip.From.Host)(PORT = 1523))    )    (CONNECT_DATA =      (SERVICE_NAME = TESTES)    )  )"
maxWait="1000"
removeAbandoned="true"
maxActive="30"
maxIdle="10"
removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
logAbandoned="true"/>
```

The above "url" property has, after the "@", the same value from my TNSNAMES.ora.
The trick is that you have to connect from crystal reports using oracle connection and using a tns name which is the same of JNDI name and save the report after connect this tns.

When executing from java, it searches the JNDI with the same name stored on the report and everything works fine.

Another thing: I had to put the context.xml in my app folder (...tomcat/webapps/MyAppName/META-INF/context.xml).